# Enabling CORS using F# and ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, f#, cors, saturn-framework

How do I enable CORS using F# and ASP.NET. I'm trying to authenticate a user with Google but I get the following error in the browser console:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed
>   access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
>   mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

A reproducible example is here https://github.com/sashang/safe-google-auth

It uses F# and the SAFE framework so you'll need that setup if you want to try and reproduce this.

You'll also need to setup a client id and secret with Google+ API (https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/plus.googleapis.com)

Once that's done add it to your environment:

**Bash:**

```
export GOOGLE_ID="client id"
export GOOGLE_SECRET="client secret"
```

**Windows Powershell:**

```
$Env:GOOLGE_ID="client id"
$Env:GOOGLE_SECRET="client secret"
```

To build it clone the repo and run

```
fake build --target run
```

Then click on the button `Auth with Google` with the browser console window open to see the error.

Answer (score 2):

In your `Server.fs` you don't call your `configure_cors` method

```
let app google_id google_secret = 
    application {
        url ("http://0.0.0.0:" + port.ToString() + "/")
        use_router webApp
        memory_cache
        use_static publicPath
        service_config configureSerialization
        use_gzip
        use_google_oauth google_id google_secret "/oauth_callback_google" []
        //use_cors "localhost:8080" configure_cors
        configure_cors // Add this line to your program

}
```

Comment: I thought the saturn framework would call it via use_cors. See the  the line above that's commented `use_cors`. I did try it with it uncommented. Do I really have to explicitly call it as `configure_cors`? If I try that it won't compile since the application is computation expression that requires something special but I have no idea what.